# What is display:ruby

Tags: css, display

While going through the css drafts spec for [display properties](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-display-3/#the-display-properties) came across this property

`display:ruby`

A little bit of search explained that is used for showing Japanese characters .

- is this the only use case? (using it for normal text doesnt do anything special , futher more, chrome marks it as a invalid property)
- how does it differ from our usual block container ?

Comment: Check this out: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/ruby-position it may help you understand what ruby is

Comment: Care if you plan to use this: https://caniuse.com/#search=display%20ruby

Answer (score 13):

[From HTML5 docs](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-ruby-element)

> The *ruby* element allows one or more spans of phrasing content to be marked with ruby annotations. **Ruby annotations are** short runs of text presented alongside base text, **primarily used in East Asian typography as a guide for pronunciation or to include other annotations**

So you basically use it for pronunciation of any language. But it does not restrict you to using it only for that.

Comment: any real time examples ? as i said... applying this to normal text doesn't do much :(

Comment: @luciferous What you expect to get using in for Latin letters text? It has it's own purpose, if you find some other ways to use it - it's up to you.

Comment: This was useful to me when I had a text and a few chips besides that text, even though I used `word-wrap` and other methods it didn't give me a cool style as `ruby`, which allowed the text to not wrap and the chips wrap

Answer (score 4):

I was having trouble with the a tag taking the whole block in an li, so, i used ruby and it didnt take the whole block space, nor did it ruin the format of the rest of the visual structure.

Comment: Hello kulkul, welcome to SO. It's great to see you are contributing, however, an answer could/should be more elaborate. Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer to gain extra insight on how to answer in a way that keeps our beloved SO to high standards.

Answer (score 2):

[From MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display):

> The element behaves like an inline element and lays out its content according to the ruby formatting model. It behaves like the corresponding HTML  elements.

You can use it together with `display: ruby-base;` and `display:ruby-text`, which similarly act like `<rb>` and `<rt>`.

To see an example on how all of these could be used:

```css
body {
  font-size: 2em;
}

ruby {
  ruby-position: above;
}

.ruby {
  display: ruby;
}

p.ruby>span:nth-child(odd) {
  display: ruby-base;
}

p.ruby>span:nth-child(even) {
  display: ruby-text;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <ruby>
      <rb>漢</rb>
      <rb>字</rb>
      <rb>が</rb>
      <rb>難</rb>
      <rb>しい</rb>
      <rp>(</rp>
      <rt>kan</rt>
      <rt>ji</rt>
      <rt>ga</rt>
      <rt>muzuka</rt>
      <rt>shii</rt>
      <rp>)</rp>
</ruby> ！
</p>

<p class="ruby">
  <span>漢</span>
  <span>kan</span>
  <span>字</span>
  <span>ji</span>
  <span>難</span>
  <span>muzuka</span>
  <span>しい</span>
  <span>shii</span>
  <span>!</span>
</p>
```